# How can data templates in generic.xaml get applied automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, datatemplate

I have a custom control that has a ContentPresenter that will have an arbitrary object set as it content. This object does not have any constraint on its type, so I want this control to display its content based on any data templates defined by application or by data templates defined in Generic.xaml. If in a application I define some data template(without a key because I want it to be applied automatically to objects of that type) and I use the custom control bound to an object of that type, the data template gets applied automatically. But I have some data templates defined for some types in the generic.xaml where I define the custom control style, and these templates are not getting applied automatically. Here is the generic.xaml :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type PredefinedType>
    <!-- template definition -->
<DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl}">
    <!-- control style -->
</Style>
```

If I set an object of type 'PredefinedType' as the content in the contentpresenter, the data template does not get applied. However, If it works if I define the data template in the app.xaml for the application thats using the custom control.

Does someone got a clue? I really cant assume that the user of the control will define this data template, so I need some way to tie it up with the custom control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources declared in Generic.xaml are only pulled in if they are directly referenced by the template being applied to a control (usually by a StaticResource reference). In this case you can't set up a direct reference so you need to use another method to package the DataTemplates with your ControlTemplate. You can do this by including them in a more local Resources collection, like ControlTemplate.Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyDataObject}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: In addition to John's correct answer, if you need to use the templates elsewhere you can bring them into the control template resources merged dictionaries from another XAML file. This allows you to reuse templates in both generic.xaml and other locations.