# How can data templates in generic.xaml get applied automatically (redux)?

Tags: wpf, themes, datatemplate

This is a follow-up to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751707/how-can-data-templates-in-generic-xaml-get-applied-automatically) posted by [Thiado de Arruda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304141/thiado-de-arruda).  In short, he wanted to have a DataTemplate in his generic.xaml file, but the template wasn't being applied.

The answer given suggested placing the DataTemplate in the ControlTemplate.Resources for the control that hosted his custom type.  This works very well, however, suppose that he needed the DataTemplate to apply in other places, not just within the host control.  Would it be necessary to copy the DataTemplate to the ControlTemplates of every other host control?

**Edit** (restating question):

I am developing a WPF application using MVVM design principles.  *MainWindow.xaml* contains the structure of the UI, and all of the styling is coded in *Themes\generic.xaml*.  (The behavior is coded in a separate view model class, but that's irrelevant.)  As part of the UI, I created a subclass of `ListBox` (`MyListBoxSubClass`) to display a collection of an ordinary .Net object of my own creation (`MyObject`).  `MyListBoxSubClass` has a style in *generic.xaml* that redefines the `Template` property, and it gets applied as expected.  I also have a `DataTemplate` for `MyObject` in *generic.xaml*, but this does not get applied.  According to the above link, I have to place the `DataTemplate` in the `Resources` collection of the `ControlTemplate` for `MyListBoxSubClass` in order for this `DataTemplate` to be applied.  This works wonderfully.

My question is how to get the `DataTemplate` to apply to `MyObject` *everywhere* in my application without having to duplicate the `DataTemplate`?  I've tried adding a key to the `DataTemplate` and referencing it where I need it, but for some reason, I get a XAML parse error at runtime, and Resharper says that it can't resolve my `DataTemplate` key.

Comment: You can add a key to DataTemplate and use it whenever you want to apply the template, you don't have to copy the entire template.

Comment: When I do that, Resharper gives me a "cannot be resolved" error, and my app crashes when trying to load that part of the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data template in a separate resource dictionary in another XAML file.

Bring the XAML file into your generic.xaml control template resources:

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
              <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="wherever.xaml" />
              </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then wherever else you want to use this data template, you can bring it into merged dictionary of resources of wherever you want - user control, window, another control template, etc...

```
<Window x:Name="someWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
              <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="wherever.xaml" />
              </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps.